# One a DELETE query, how to know that there was nothing to delete?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, select

I'm currently polishing a C# app in relation with a SQL-Server base.

It's quite simple, you can add or remove entries from the SQL table via some fields from the application.

Question is : 
On a Delete action, I've made this kind of query :

```
DELETE FROM table 
 WHERE ID = @ID
```

It deletes what I ask it to delete, BUT what if the query doesn't find anything in the DB ?
How can I detect that ? 
Because in this case, the application deletes nothing, and no exception is raised.
To make it short, I'd just like to tell the user that there's nothing to delete in this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that your query will delete *all* data from the table if *any* of the rows have `ID=@ID`.  That is, you will either delete the whole table or nothing. Is that what you intend?

Comment: No, and thank you for pointing that out by the way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `SqlCommand` object, there is a method called **[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)**. The method return how many rows are affected. So, zero means none.

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <== this
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach is good if only that particular query is called. But in the problem there is no such claim .. so I am wondering how this post is so good :)

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from table where ID=@id
select @@rowcount
```

This will return how many rows there were actually deleted. You do not need the exists.

Comment: That query has a different behaviour to the one in the post.  The OP might well need the `exists`!

Comment: I think you should read what exists does in this case. It's a row by row comparison with the row's ID.

Comment: I think you should reread the original query.  If there was *any single row* in the table with `ID=@ID` then the exists would return `true` *for all rows* and thus all rows would be deleted.  (That said, the OP has confirmed that this was an error on his part, so your change in behaviour is welcomed.)

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `@@ROWCOUNT` variable

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx